# How can I resize UIView width when some view hidden?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

[image]

The above Image is captured from `storyboard`.
It is constructed like as follows:
`UIView` (include `UILabel` and `UIProgressView`) <--2px spacing --> `UIActivityIndicatorView` <---6px spacing ---> `UIButton`

I want the `UIView` to increase its width to button when `UIActivityIndicatorView` hidden as follows:
   `UIView`( include `UILabel` and `UIProgressView`) <---6 space---> `UIButton`

How can I do that?? Let me Know. Please.

Comment: there are 2 ways i would do this, set the frame of that view when UIActivityIndicatorView hide/show, or use autolayouts, change the width constraint content when UIActivityIndicatorView hide/show.

you can find a lot of well-organized tutorial for both ways on Google

Comment: Thank you. I found that changing the constraint to 0, but it didn't work. Could you link about changing the width constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/bilobatum/ActivityIndicatorDemo

[image]

Make the button's intrinsic content size along the horizontal axis required (i.e., priority 1000). This prevents the layout from being ambiguous along the horizontal axis.

[image]

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *activityIndicatorWidthConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
// spacerConstraint is the horizontal spacer constraint between the activity indicator and the gray view
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *spacerConstraint;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (IBAction)stopButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.enabled = NO;

    self.activityIndicatorWidthConstraint.constant = 0;
    self.spacerConstraint.constant = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.activityIndicator.alpha = 0.0;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        //[NSLayoutConstraint reportAmbiguity:nil];
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: @nao0811ta Updated answer with gray view's subviews. GitHub project is also updated.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works..I'm sorry for frequent question. I'm a beginner. T_T

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Auto-layout, consider setting the width of the UIActivityIndicatorView to 0 when you disable it. This won't be exactly what you need, but it's close.

Comment: It can't be applied to 0 with following code.

CGRect rect = self.activityView.frame;
rect.size.width = 0;
self.activityView.frame = rect;

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your `UILabel` is called `_label`, `UIProgressView` is called `_progressView` and `UIActivityIndicator` is called `_activityIndicator`.

When you hide your `_activityIndicator`, call this block of code:

```
[_label setFrame:CGRectMake(_label.frame.origin.x, _label.frame.origin.y, _label.frame.size.width + _activityIndicator.frame.size.width + 2, _label.frame.size.height)];
[_progressView setFrame:CGRectMake(_progressView.frame.origin.x, _progressView.frame.origin.y, _progressView.frame.size.width + _activityIndicator.frame.size.width + 2, _progressView.frame.size.height)];
```

When `_activityIndicator` shows again:

```
[_label setFrame:CGRectMake(_label.frame.origin.x, _label.frame.origin.y, _label.frame.size.width - _activityIndicator.frame.size.width - 2, _label.frame.size.height)];
[_progressView setFrame:CGRectMake(_progressView.frame.origin.x, _progressView.frame.origin.y, _progressView.frame.size.width - _activityIndicator.frame.size.width - 2, _progressView.frame.size.height)];
```

Remember, that `Autolayout` should be turned off, if you want to manually set the frames! It is very simple: just uncheck the "Use Autolayout" feature in File Inspector:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying. but I'm using auto layout with other components.
So i want to use auto layout. Do you have another solution with auto layout?